# My commandmanager floats. How do I get it back to the top of the screen?

Tags: solidworks

this is silly, but my command manager has been floating for years, and I've never figured out how to get it to go back to it's bar at the top of the screen..  any help appreciated!  i'm sure this will sound like a novice question..

Comment: What version of SolidWorks are you using? You should be able to drag the command manager near the top of the screen, at which point point you can drop it over an icon that pops up to re-dock it. I certainly wouldn't recommend **deleting a registry key** to solve this problem.

Comment: I tried various versions of that, and didn't get anywhere.  I also installed a new version of sw, and the problem persisted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I do you can try deleting this registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SolidWorks\SOLIDWORKS 2017\User Interface. It holds all customizations for the user interface that you applied. It shouldn't interfere with solidworks operations but I'd still create a backup before deleting the key.

1 Click Start

2 type run and click on the first result

3 type regedit.exe

4 in the editor navigate to the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
\SolidWorks\SOLIDWORKS 2017\User Interface

5 Right click it and press export to backup existing values

6 Delete this key

Comment: thank you  for the suggestion.  could  you be more specific as to where I might find it?  appData? ..

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't allow me to format comment. changed my answer.

Comment: wow.. so far so good.  ...now I just have to get used to where everything is now, I don't seem to be able to move it the way I used to.  technically, you've solved half the problem (by far the most important half).  the other half is how to get the bars to the top of the screen.  I might decide they're fine where they are, in which case, I'll accept your answer :-)